# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'README.md'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, selendroid

I'm trying to use selendroid in my app as webscraper, but I get this error "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'README.md'" . 
Any thoughts on how to fix it?

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.startandroid.testselenium2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('D:\\chromedriver\\selendroid-client-0.17.0.jar')
    implementation files('D:\\chromedriver\\selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `android` closure:

```
packagingOptions {
     exclude 'README.md'
}
```